# Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Tags: python, list, tuples, nested-lists

I have N number of elements present on the list. The elements can be an integer, a list of integers or tuple, or a list of lists or strings. I need to extract all the elements and store them on a different list.
example:

```
input_list = [1, [2, [3, [4], 5, 6]], None, 'Abc', (7, 8, [9, 10, [11]], )]  

output_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, None, 'Abc', 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
```

I have tried to solve it by using a recursive function call but failed.

Is there any python function for this? Please help me to solve this.

Comment: You have to provide [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), also what exactly failed?

Comment: If you are asking if Python has an analogue of `flat` in Perl, the answer is no. Show us the recursive function you tried that didn't work.

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 2):

Here is your recursive function

```
input_list = [1, [2, [3, [4], 5, 6]], None, 'Abc', (7, 8, [9, 10, [11]],)]
output_list = []


def sub_items(item):
    if not hasattr(item, '__iter__') or isinstance(item, str):
        output_list.append(item)
    else:
        for sub_item in item:
            sub_items(sub_item)


for item in input_list:
    sub_items(item)
print(output_list)
```

Output is

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, None, 'Abc', 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from iteration_utilities import deepflatten

multi_depth_list = [[0,1], [[5]], [6,4]]

flatten_list = list(deepflatten(multi_depth_list))

print(flatten_list)'
```

Output:

[0, 1, 5, 6, 4]

Comment: This gives an error on the example the the author asked about. `int` object is not iterable.

Comment: The example has (at least) three levels of sub-nesting.